# MySQL Update Column +1?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, aggregate-functions

I was wondering what would be the easiest way to update a column by +1? I will be updating a post count of a category based on when users submits a new post.

Thanks.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand. Do you wish to update all rows setting the value of your column to its old value + 1?

Comment: @Benoit: The OP wants to store & update the post count related to the category.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The easiest way is to *not* store the count, relying on the COUNT aggregate function to reflect the value as it is in the database:

```
   SELECT c.category_name,
          COUNT(p.post_id) AS num_posts
     FROM CATEGORY c
LEFT JOIN POSTS p ON p.category_id = c.category_id
```

You can [create a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html) to house the query mentioned above, so you can query the view just like you would a table...

But if you're set on storing the number, use:

```
UPDATE CATEGORY
   SET count = count + 1
 WHERE category_id = ?
```

..replacing "?" with the appropriate value.

Comment: Thanks. Initially my thought to determine the amount of posts in a category would be to check the post tables for a cat_id matching that category and then add them up. Thought this may be resource consuming or less efficient than writing directly to that table.

Comment: It's very quick when you have an index on `p.post_id`.

Comment: UPDATE CATEGORY SET count = count + 1; perfect solution.

Answer (score 38):

You can do:

`UPDATE categories SET posts = posts + 1 WHERE category_id = 42;`

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
update table
set columnname = columnname + 1
where id = <some id>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
update post set count = count + 1 where id = 101
```

Answer (score 3):

```
update table_name set field1 = field1 + 1;
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? The question is nearly nine years old, and the same way has been given in answers multiple times

Comment: I'm using database for 6-7 years. & yesterday I found that solution helpful. So please give positive feedback for my answer.

Comment: Please provide more explanation first - why did you post that answer, while the exact same solution (okay, with another table and column name) has been posted multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

How to update order column Count value

Try

```
  UPDATE order SET                                      
    Order_Count = Order_Count + 100
  WHERE 
    Order_ID = '1234'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update TABLENAME
set COLUMNNAME = COLUMNNAME + 1
where id = 'YOURID'
```