# PHP or MySql Wont Update Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have posted this question 2 times none worked I re scripted it and now I'm having more problems

Here's my code on the first page:

```
<?php

$host="XXXX"; // Host name 
$username="XXXX"; // Mysql username 
$password="XXXX"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="XXXX"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="XXXX"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// select record from mysql 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name order by id desc";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<table background='images/view.png' width='50%'>
<tr>
<th align='center'>Post #</th><th align='center'>Submition By</th><th     align='center'>ScreenName</th><th align='center'>Password</th><th align='center'>Does This     Work?</th><th align='center'>Vote</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='lime' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
</th>
<th align='center'>
<hr color='gold' width='100%'/>
</th>
</tr>
<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['id']; ?> </b></i></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['yname']; ?> </b></i>    </td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['username']; ?></b></i></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['password']; ?></b></i></td>
<td background='transparent' align='center'><i><b><? echo $rows['works']; ?>% Yes <font  color='transparent'>||||</font>&nbsp; <? echo $rows['dworks']; ?>% No</b></i>
<td background='transpatent' align='center'><i><b><a href='works.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>'><img src='images/ThumbsUp.png' height='30' width='30'>  </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='dworks.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>'><img   src='images/ThumbsDown.png' height='30' width='30'></a>

</td> 
</tr>

<?php
// close while loop 
}
?>

<?php
// close connection; 
mysql_close();
?>

</table>
```

im not sure if this page is part of the problem yet...

here is the second page

```
<?php
$host="XXXX"; // Host name 
$username="XXXX"; // Mysql username 
$password="XXXX"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="XXXX"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="XXXX"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database 
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>


<?php
$host="XXXX"; // Host name 
$username="XXXX"; // Mysql username 
$password="XXXX"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="XXXX"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="XXXX"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE `$host`.`$username` 
SET `works` = `works` + 1 WHERE `$db_name`.`id` = '".$id."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

I'm getting the error on my custom error page and I don't know why .. I'm trying to make it add +1 to a column on my table named works the default value is 0 and i cant get it to add +1 say the value is 1 and someone clicks the image link the value changes to 2 and another click it goes to 3 so on and so forth

Yes this is real mysql login information this is not my perm site its just to test my code to put on my real site so I don't care sharing that

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes those are but like i said i dont mind its not my real mysql database its to test code for my real site

Comment: What's the error? Be careful about taking a GET parameter and putting it inside the query, it could be used for an injection.

Comment: What is the error are you getting?

Comment: @Jackopo i have an custom error set up in the last set of php code im getting that error called ERROR!

Comment: remove that custom error!!!!

Comment: i removed the custom error and now the page is blank and mysql wont update still

Comment: echo mysql_error() at end of last mysql query..

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a7864418/public_html/works.php on line 36 after making

Comment: // update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE `$host`.`$username` 
SET `works` = `works` + 1 WHERE `$db_name`.`id` = '".$id."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql)  mysql_error()";

Comment: @TheWhiteHatter there is a stray `"` at the end of the line

Comment: i removed that but im getting furhur with sheikh's answer i now know the problem is in the last <?php area on my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change following

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
```

to

```
$link=mysql_connect($host, $username, $password); 
if (!$link) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected=mysql_select_db("$db_name", $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Not selected : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

To fetch data and print

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo 'id: '. $row['id'].'<br />'; // replace with real field name
        echo 'name: '. $row['name']'<br />'; // replace with real field name
    }
 }
```

Comment: what <?php is it in the first , second or third

Comment: @TheWhiteHatter, you didn't print anything, check the update.

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['id']; // replace with real field name
    echo $row['name']; // replace with real field name
}  what <?php collum 1,2,3

Comment: found it and i got this back 4test

Answer (score -1):

changed last query to $sql="UPDATE tylted SET works = works + 1 WHERE id = $id;";
$result=mysql_query($sql); and it works i google searched for 9 or 10 min and found
[MySQL Update Column +1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866524/mysql-update-column-1) i searched for this here also and it didnt work thanks people for helping as much as u did